# How to create Password Expiration And User must Update his Password without using Spring Security?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a task to create password expiration, i.e. Password should valid up to only 10 days and after that user should update password , Thanks in Advance

**User.Groovy**

```
import java.util.Date;


[User authentication in User controller ][1]  class User {

    int userId
    String userName
    String password
    String email
    String mobileNumber
    String modifiedBy
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grails spring security / Acegi. Custom User + Password expired management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864749/grails-spring-security-acegi-custom-user-password-expired-management)

Comment: Thanks, Is there any possible to do without using spring security thanks in advance! @Rcordoval

Comment: When a user updates his/her password, store the current time in database. When he/she logs in, check if the last password change occurred more than 10 days ago.

Comment: Thanks, am bit new to grails can you please provide related source please , thanks in advance. @JBNizet